# problema al saltar mario bros

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy tratando de hacer saltar a un mario bros. Se logra el objetivo (que salte), pero tengo que poner un System.out.println() en el metodo run para que funcione.
Anteriormente tuve un problema similar, me recomendaron usa synchronized. Pero he intentado todas las combinaciones posibles y no funciona sin el system.out.println().
Estuve averiguando que ahora no se usa sinchronized sino que Lock y condition, pero no supe implementarlo, desde ya quedo muy agradecido por su ayuda.
Les dejo el codigo.

Clase principal

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ventana ventana = new Ventana();
        
    }
}
```

Clase Ventana

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Ventana extends JFrame implements KeyListener,Runnable{

    Etapa panel;
    
    public Ventana() {
        setBounds(0,0,500,500);
        panel = new Etapa("mario bros.png", new Point(100,300));
        add(panel);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Thread hilo = new Thread(this);
        hilo.start();
        setVisible(true);
        
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {      
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
            panel.setSaltar();
        }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            panel.moverDerecha();
        }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            panel.moverIzquierda();
        }
            
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {       
    }
    
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
                panel.repaint();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Clase Etapa

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Etapa extends Component implements Runnable{
    
    Image mario;
    public Point posicion;
    public boolean saltar = false;
    public boolean derechaOIzquierda = true;
    
    public Etapa(String ruta, Point posicion) {
        
        try {
            mario =  ImageIO.read(new File(ruta));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.posicion = posicion;
        Thread hilo = new Thread(this);
        hilo.start();
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(mario,posicion.x,posicion.y,40,40,null);
    }
    
    public void setSaltar() {
        saltar = true;      
    }
    
    public void saltar() throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                posicion.y -= 2;
                if(derechaOIzquierda)
                    posicion.x += 2;
                else
                    posicion.x -= 2;
                Thread.sleep(5);
                
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                posicion.y += 2;
                if(derechaOIzquierda)
                    posicion.x += 2;
                else
                    posicion.x -= 2;
                Thread.sleep(5);
            
        }
    }
    
    public void moverDerecha() {
        posicion.x += 4;
    } 
    
    public void moverIzquierda() {
        posicion.x -= 4;
    }
    
    
    public  void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(saltar) {
                try {
                    saltar();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                saltar  = false;
                //System.out.println("salto");
            }
            //System.out.println("funciona");
        }   
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentas, el problema está relacionado a concurrencia/sincronización, si notas el método que usas para que Mario salte `setSaltar()` usa la variable `saltar`, que también se define en el hilo dentro del método `run()`, la mayoría de las ocasiones se provoca un problema de concurrencia lo cual impedirá que Mario pueda saltar.

```
    public void setSaltar() {
        saltar = true;      
    }

   public  void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(saltar) {
                ...
                ...
                saltar  = false;
            }
        }   
    }
```

Te sugiero usar [**ReentrantLock**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) que implementa la interface [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) (para usar su método [**lock()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lock--)) y la interface [**Condition**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) para este caso

> [**ReentrantLock**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) Un bloqueo de exclusión mutua reentrante con el
> mismo comportamiento básico y semántica que el bloqueo de monitor
> implícito al que se accede mediante métodos y sentencias
> sincronizados, pero con capacidades ampliadas. Un ReentrantLock es
> propiedad del subproceso que se bloqueó con éxito por última vez, pero
> que aún no lo ha desbloqueado. Un subproceso que invoque el bloqueo
> regresará, adquiriendo con éxito el bloqueo, cuando el bloqueo no sea
> propiedad de otro subproceso. El método regresará inmediatamente si el
> hilo actual ya posee el bloqueo. Esto se puede verificar usando los
> métodos isHeldByCurrentThread() y getHoldCount().
>
> [**Condition**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) Los factores de condición eliminan los métodos del
> monitor de objetos (esperar, notificar y notificar a todos) en objetos
> distintos para dar el efecto de tener múltiples conjuntos de espera
> por objeto, combinándolos con el uso de implementaciones de bloqueo
> arbitrarias. Cuando un Bloqueo reemplaza el uso de métodos y
> sentencias sincronizados, una Condición reemplaza el uso de los
> métodos del monitor de Objetos. Las condiciones (también conocidas
> como colas de condiciones o variables de condición) proporcionan un
> medio para que un subproceso suspenda la ejecución (para "esperar")
> hasta que otro subproceso notifique que alguna condición de estado
> ahora puede ser verdadera. Debido a que el acceso a esta información
> de estado compartida ocurre en diferentes subprocesos, debe
> protegerse, por lo que se asocia un bloqueo de algún tipo con la
> condición. La propiedad clave que proporciona la espera de una
> condición es que libera atómicamente el bloqueo asociado y suspende el
> subproceso actual, al igual que Object.wait.
>
> [**Lock**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) Las implementaciones de bloqueo proporcionan operaciones de
> bloqueo más extensas que las que se pueden obtener usando métodos y
> sentencias sincronizados. Permiten una estructuración más flexible,
> pueden tener propiedades bastante diferentes y pueden admitir varios
> objetos de condición asociados. Un candado es una herramienta para
> controlar el acceso a un recurso compartido por varios subprocesos.
> Por lo general, un bloqueo proporciona acceso exclusivo a un recurso
> compartido: solo un subproceso a la vez puede adquirir el bloqueo y
> todo acceso al recurso compartido requiere que primero se adquiera el
> bloqueo. Sin embargo, algunos bloqueos pueden permitir el acceso
> simultáneo a un recurso compartido, como el bloqueo de lectura de un
> ReadWriteLock.
>
> [**Lock.lock()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#lock--) Adquiere el bloqueo. Si el bloqueo no está
> disponible, el subproceso actual se desactiva para fines de
> programación de subprocesos y permanece inactivo hasta que se adquiere
> el bloqueo.

[image: Jorgesys Java Mario Bros.]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Etapa extends Component implements Runnable{

    Image mario;
    public Point posicion;
    public boolean saltar = false;
    public boolean derechaOIzquierda = true;
    private Lock lock;
    private Condition condition;

    public Etapa(String ruta, Point posicion) {
        try {
            mario =  ImageIO.read(new File(ruta));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.posicion = posicion;

        lock = new ReentrantLock(); /***/
        condition = lock.newCondition();/***/

        Thread hilo = new Thread(this); //Salta!
        hilo.start();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(mario,posicion.x,posicion.y,40,40,null);
    }

    public void setSaltar() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            saltar = true;
            condition.signal();
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }


    }

    public void saltar() throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            posicion.y -= 2;
            if(derechaOIzquierda)
                posicion.x += 2;
            else
                posicion.x -= 2;
            Thread.sleep(5);

        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            posicion.y += 2;
            if(derechaOIzquierda)
                posicion.x += 2;
            else
                posicion.x -= 2;
            Thread.sleep(5);

        }
    }

    public void moverDerecha() {
        posicion.x += 4;
    }

    public void moverIzquierda() {
        posicion.x -= 4;
    }


    public  void run() {
        while(true) {
            lock.lock(); /***/
            //if(saltar) {
                try {
                    while(!saltar){
                        condition.await();
                    }
                    saltar();
                    saltar = false; /***/
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
                //saltar  = false;
                //System.out.println("salto");
            //}
            //System.out.println("funciona");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy completa tu respuesta. Conoces algún libro para profundizar sobre hilos?

Comment: Hola Julio, actualmente puedes encontrar bastante información, pero te recomiendo revisar sobre concurrencia y multithreading aquí: https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/index.html